# Exception writing document id to the index; possible analysis error

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am getting the above error while indexing the documents.

```
<field name="a_suggest" type="my_suggest_field" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="b_suggest" type="my_suggest_field" indexed="true" stored="false" />
<field name="c_suggest" type="my_suggest_field" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

  <fieldType name="my_suggest_field" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="10" minGramSize="2"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

And I am getting error when calling..

```
server.add(documents);
```

First of all, what is the meaning of **Possible analysis error**? Is it related to `my_suggest_field` index analyzer. Is it due to the order of the tokens, filters in the index analyzer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to create a separate field types for `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` and normal suggest.

```
  <field name="my_suggest" type="my_suggest_field" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="my_suggest_ngram" type="my_suggest_ngram_field" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

  <fieldType name="my_suggest_field" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>

  <fieldType name="my_suggest_ngram_field" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 7):

I am going to piggy back off this question because it is one of the first ones that comes up when looking for this issue and there are no general answers.

I was getting the same problem when trying to use the update API to add a document using a json.  Come to find out one of my fields in solr was not formatted correctly as I was trying to save an XML string into a string field.  I had to change the field to text_general.

The error is basically saying that what you are entering might not fit with your schema.  Check each of your fields by adding them to the update 1 at a time.  Then change as necessary.