# unable to reindex Solr data: Exception writing document id Assignment 1 to the index; possible analysis error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have setup solr search in my rails app but currently I am having much issues with that.

1st. I am forced to stop and start, reindex solr on each system restart. It is automatically started as apache service but still forced to stop n delete solr folder and reinstall and reindex again.

Using command below I am having issue # 2:

```
    rm solr/ -rf && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start 
&& RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

2nd. When I try to reindex I am having below error:

```
Successfully started Solr ...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring...
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: 'Exception writing document id Assignment 1 to the index; possible analysis error.','code'=>400}}

URI: http://localhost:8983/solr/development/update?wt=ruby
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}
Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\"..complete XML DATA.......
Backtrace: /home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@management/gems/rsolr-1.1.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:288:in `adapt_response'
/home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@management/gems/rsolr-1.1.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:189:in `execute'
/home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@management/gems/rsolr-1.1.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `send_and_receive'
/home/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@management/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
```

Comment: Can you share your schema file? Solr version? Stacktrace of error? My first guess will be you are putting the wrong type of value (a string perhaps) into a numeric field (id field? ) . See this: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Exception-writing-document-to-the-index-possible-analysis-error-tp4174845p4174865.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531404/exception-writing-document-id-to-the-index-possible-analysis-error

Comment: Same issue , I am also facing.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad as above jay said this: "My first guess will be you are putting the wrong type of value (a string perhaps) into a numeric field (id field? )" so I have fixed my issue my going in my each models and fixed my data mappings correctly. Please review you models again to see you mappings on fields.